How should I optimize a PID in Webots correctly?
As stated above, I need to optimize the PID gains (the feedback) in the torque controller for trajectory tracking I am currently doing.
This is what I have done until now:

Begin simple, with just one degree of freedom (basically a vertical pendulum under gravity effects. There is a motor in the hinge it is attached to).

Add gravity compensation as extra feedback.

Tune the gains manually to check the code works (successfully done). The test was done with a reference angle trajectory as follows: accelerate for the first 2 seconds, keep a constant angular velocity for the next 12 seconds, decelerate for the next 2 seconds, and finally keep a constant value angle.


Now, here is the tricky part I am currently stuck at:

Define an objective function to minimize with scipy. In this case, I choose IAE (Integral of absolute error) to begin with, with the gains Kp, Kd, and Ki, and the total integration time T
as input arguments. I don't know what to do here, because I know that when I had to define the constraints and upper and lower bounds, I will require torque limits, joint limits, velocity limits, etc., so, I don't know exactly should I define the inputs here such that everything fits.

I currently don't know how to do this procedure in the optimization: a) Run simulation and calculate the value of the objective function for a given input. b) Calculate the next input through optimization algorithm. c) Reset  Simulation (From this point onwards is the main problem). d) Run simulation again for the new input and calculate the new value of the objective function. e) Repeat until the absolute value of the difference between two consecutive values of the objective function is less than a threshold.


My questions:

How should I go about step 5? I need to know how to do the reset and run the the next iteration in Webots.

When I go for more degrees of freedom and I have a MIMO system, what should I use as objective function?

Any recommendation for multiple degrees of freedom in general?


Thanks in advance

One question per post, please.
